# Unable to use vanilla JS for AWS Cognito, and get AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined

Tags: amazon-cognito

I follow the instructions from https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Here is my html code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Testing AWS Cognito</title>
    <script src="/js/aws/aws-cognito-sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.211.1.min.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"> <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username"><br/>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone"><br/>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br/>
      <button id="signup" onClick="register()" >Register</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      const register = function() {
        console.log("onclick loading now");
        var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
      }
    </script>

  </body>


</html>
```

But when I run it, it gives me:

> "signup_aws_test.html:32 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined"

I am very sure both files are loaded before I click the button.

in the aws-cognito-sdk.js, I can see that AmazonCognitoIdentity exists and exports.  It doesn't seems like it is in the global namespace though.
Do i need to run something else to "Load" it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
The file name MUST BE
"amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"

although the content the same, the filename matters.
Once I change it to amazon-cognito-identity.min.js, it works.